# multiple response in single array in golang

Tags: api, go, response, go-gin

I am new to golang . and I want to get my response as multiple result. I do some method but I need to change that one

```
impartErrl := ph.profileService.ValidateSchema(gojsonschema.NewStringLoader(string(b)))
        if impartErrl != nil {
            ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, impart.ErrorResponse(impartErrl))
            return
        }
```

---

```
func (ps *profileService) ValidateSchema(document gojsonschema.JSONLoader) (errors []impart.Error) {
    result, err := gojsonschema.Validate(ps.schemaValidator, document)
    if err != nil {
        ps.SugaredLogger.Error(err.Error())
        return impart.ErrorResponse(
            impart.NewError(impart.ErrBadRequest, "unable to validate schema"),
        )
    }

    if result.Valid() {
        return nil
    }
    // msg := fmt.Sprintf("%v validations errors.\n", len(result.Errors()))
    msg := "validations errors"
    for i, desc := range result.Errors() {
        msg += fmt.Sprintf("%v: %s\n", i, desc)
        er := impart.NewError(impart.ErrValidationError, fmt.Sprintf("%s ", desc), impart.ErrorKey(desc.Field()))
        errors = append(errors, er)
    }
    return errors
}
```

---

```
func NewError(err error, msg string, args ...interface{}) Error {
    key := GetErrorKey(args...)
    return impartError{
        err: err,
        msg: msg,
        key: key,
    }
}
```

---

```
func ErrorResponse(err interface{}) []Error {
    var errorResponse []Error
    switch err.(type) {
    case Error:
        errorResponse = []Error{err.(Error)}
    case []Error:
        errorResponse = err.([]Error)
    default:
        errorResponse = []Error{
            NewError(ErrUnknown, fmt.Sprintf("%v", err)),
        }
    }
    return errorResponse
}
```

---

```
type Error interface {
    error
    HttpStatus() int
    ToJson() string
    Err() error
    Msg() string
}
```

Now I am getting the output as

```
[
    {
        "error": "validation error",
        "msg": "email: Does not match format 'email' ",
        "key": "email"
    },
    {
        "error": "validation error",
        "msg": "screenName: String length must be greater than or equal to 4 ",
        "key": "screenName"
    }
]
```

but I require my response as

```
{
     0 :{
            "error": "validation error",
            "msg": "email: Does not match format 'email' ",
            "key": "email"
        },
    1 : {
        "error": "unable to complete the request",
        "msg": "invalid screen name, must be alphanumeric characters only",
        "key": "screen_name"
    }

}
```

How can I get these type of response. ? because in ios app while parsing the response [] showing error. so I need to change the output.

please help me.

Comment: so `ErrorResponse` should return a  `map[int32]Error` instead of `[]Error` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ErrorResponse` func should return a `map[int]Error` instead of `[]Error`. As Example:

```
func ErrorResponse(err interface{}) map[int]Error {
    errorResponse := map[int]Error{}
    switch e := err.(type) {
    case Error:
        errorResponse[0] = e
    case []Error:
        for i, k := range e {
            errorResponse[i] = k
        }
    default:
        errorResponse[0] = NewError(ErrUnknown, fmt.Sprintf("%v", err))
    }
    return errorResponse
}
```

Comment: I'd check two things: 1) that `encoding/json` sorts the map on its keys before marshaling, and if it does not, that 2) the keys appearing out of natural sorting order does not break "the ios app". I'm mentioning this because in Go, map traversal does not provide any guarantees about the order in which its keys are visited.

Comment: @Matteo  using this i get the  required output.